# pycharm не находит constant в библиотеке __init__.py

Tags: pycharm, keras, tensorflow, anaconda

При запуске кода пайчарм выделяет "constant" и при наведении курсора пишет "cannot find reference 'constant' in '**init**/py'" 
версия питона 3,7,4, версия cuda и cudnn 10.0, анаконда 3.7
Насколько я понял, пайчарм не может найти константу в библиотеке. Как исправить это ? Важный момент в том, что он когда не дописываешь const, тебе его предлагает пайчарм[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])
x2 = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8])
x3 = tf.constant([9, 10, 11, 12])

result = tf.multiply(x1, x2)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переустановить модуль в консоли или в загрузчике PyCharm-а. Возможна ошибка в файловой директории.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть исправлено в последнем 2019.3 EAP билде https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил,так и не понял в чем именно было дело. Помогло понижение версии TensorFlow до 1.15 (версия для видеокарты),  керас до 2.3.1 и питон до 3.6. Решение нашлось эмпирическим путём.